# How query specific item from json object which has dictionary?

Tags: c#, linq, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

How to query the below json object collection using SQL/LINQ, to get 'ordername' which has item(s) ONLY from particular 'factory' i.e., factory1?

Note: json object collections are nothing but cosmos db collection

I know below json structure can be improved, by replacing dictionary with array but that change not feasible at the moment.

```
  {
  id:123,
  ordername:order1,
  itemdictionary: {
    item1: {
      id: "item1",
      name: "milk",
      manufacture:
       {
       name:factory1,
       location:location1
       }
    },
    item2: {
      id: "item2",
      name: "curd",
      manufacture:
       {
       name:factory2,
       location:location2
       }
    }
   }
   orderamt:"5$"
  }

{
  id:1234,
  ordername:order2,
  itemdictionary: {
    item1: {
      id: "item1";
      name: "honey",
      manufacture:
       {
       name:factory3,
       location:location3
       }
    },
    item2: {
      id: "item2",
      name: "milk",
      manufacture:
       {
       name:factory1,
       location:location1
       }
    }
  }
  orderamt:"7$"
}

c# representation:

public class OrderModel
{  
    public string OrderAmt{ get; set; }
    public string Id{ get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,ItemDescription> ItemDictionary{ get; set; }
    public class ItemDescription
    {
      public string Id { get; set; }
      public string Name{ get; set; }
      public Manufacture Manufacture{ get; set; }
    }
} 

public class Manufacture 
{
    public string Location{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
 }
```

**Query tried**, returning all records without applying filter but need to apply filter like (manufacture.name == "factory1") :

```
 var query = dbClient.CreateDocumentQuery<OrderModel>(collectionUri, 
 feedOptions).Where(w => w.ItemDictionary.Values.Where(i => 
 i.manufacture.name == "factory1") != null).AsDocumentQuery();
```

Comment: You json is not valid as I see. Can you provide a valid Json?

Comment: Short answer; you can't do this in a query. Cosmos provides no way to dynamically define property names in your filter clause. You'll either need to perform filtering client side or make a query that checks each `item#` hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, like you mentioned yourself, this dictionary is a rather inefficient model for your needs. You really should plan to migrate to a better model at some point, it may be easier (and cheaper) than constantly hassling with issues like you are having now.

I don't think you can do it with a clean indexed SQL query alone. What you could try:

#### Append factory summary to model

If you do have some tools set up to upgrade models, then you could normalize the used factories to `/factories[]` or similar. This extra field could be indexed and queried trivially and efficiently.

Note that adding a field to cosmosDB will not break your existing applications. It's cheap and simple as long as you have a way of enforcing this new array will be kept in sync on insert/update (ex via some pipe on data layer) + upgrading any old documents via your schema upgrade tools.

#### Prefilter in server, final filter in client

If you really-really can't touch the model at all then best you can do, is work with partial filter on cosmosDB side and apply final filter in client. Depending on data, this can be costly and messy.

For example:

1. Set up index for first item:

   1. `/itemdictionary/item1/manufacture/name`
2. SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM c
where (c.itemdictionary.item1.manufacture.name = @factory)
and ( not is_defined(c.itemdictionary.item2.manufacture.name) or c.itemdictionary.item2.manufacture.name = @factory)
and ( not is_defined(c.itemdictionary.item3.manufacture.name) or c.itemdictionary.item3.manufacture.name = @factory)
and ( not is_defined(c.itemdictionary.item4.manufacture.name) or c.itemdictionary.item4.manufacture.name = @factory)
```

3. In client after SQL query has returned the results, eliminate results with other factories. That is execute `.AsDocumentQuery()` before applying the predicate `.Where(w => w.ItemDictionary.All(i => i.manufacture.name == "factory1"))` on fetched results.

This is inefficient if orders got many items on average and the chosen N items do not limit the results sufficiently. Note that you don't have to choose prefilter indexes sequentially: depending on data it may make more sense to precheck `[1,2, 10, 20]` or similar. You can also play with N to get the best out of prefilter for the average case.

#### Filter in client with UDF

I usually hate UDFs due to their development cost and maintenance pains, but [it is an option to script the filter with JS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-udfs) (which can do anything) and do all the filtering on server side.

WIth UDF you do save on bandwidth, but do note though:

1. UDF is mixing your querying logic to data layer. All clients of this data will share a single UDF version on server.
2. You still need to prefilter with an indexable property to avoid a costly full-scan.
3. UDF queries are RU-costly. Full-scan + UDF is usually a no-go.

Comment: I don't have comsosV2 API at hand to check types, but you should apply that predicate not on cosmosDB, but on C# objects. Put in a `ToList()` or similar before making the `All(predicate)` filtering.

Comment: Query tried out without success. Exception received , "System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Myfunc. Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core: Method 'All' is not supported., Windows/10.0.19044 documentdb-netcore-sdk/2.11.0."                                            
    var query = dbClient.CreateDocumentQuery<OrderModel>(collectionUri, 
 feedOptions).Where(w => w.ItemDictionary.Values.All(i => 
 i.manufacture.name == "factory1") != null).AsDocumentQuery();

Comment: That's why I said: "execute .AsDocumentQuery() >>BEFORE<< applying the predicate".

Comment: BEFORE applying the predicate means (without any filter) Im going to fetch nearly a million db documents each time the function runs which is not acceptable. Idea to fetch the ONLY records which satisfies the filter coz function will run for every 5 mins, fetch millions db documents every 5 mins will take RUs over the roof

Comment: That's why proposed solution describes "Prefilter in server" part (see SQL query). `.All()` is the "final filter in client"-part.
If there are no good-enough choices for N in prefilter to bring RU to acceptable levels, then sry, you must fall back to tricks with model or go UDF way (which is still RU-wise costly, but will skip download part). Your model will put the cost on you until you fix it ;)